# CAGradientLayer with 4 Colors in 4 Different Corners

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, cagradientlayer

Is it possible to create a gradient in iOS (I'm using Swift, but an example in Objective-C could also be helpful) that has 4 different colors, but where the colors each emanate from a different corner?

I've created a gradient that can go either topleft->bottomright or bottomleft->topright in terms of where I can place colors, but that's only for 2 colors. Here is the code I have attempted for that:

```
let gradientColors: Array <AnyObject> = [bottomColor1.CGColor, topColor2.CGColor]
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
```

this successfully creates a 2 color gradient from one corner to another with `bottomColor1` and `topColor2` being `UIColor`s. How, though, would I create a similar gradient with 2 additional colors in the two other corners?

Comment: As far as I know, only linear and radial shadings are supported by Core Graphics.

Comment: Wouldn't this be linear, just with more than 2 colors?

Comment: No, a gradient layer can only do piecewise linear shadings. The intermediate points in `locations` are in the parameter space, not arbitrary points in the view. Compare http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92421-cgshading-line-triangle.html.

Comment: Ok, I understand that `locations` is just in the parameter space. You previously mentioned Gouraud shading as a possible solution, but that there's no way to do that natively, basically?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Perhaps you can overlay 4 linear shadings, each going from a solid color in one corner to a transparent white in the opposite corner. Just an idea.

Comment: That's an idea...how would I overlay them? Would I just draw 4 gradients into a single space?

Comment: You could create 4 gradient layers and add each one with `yourView.layer.addSublayer(gradlayerN)`. But I don't know if that gives satisfying results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for @Martin R's suggestions, here is some code that creates a blend that seems to work pretty well. Since there are so many colors it gets pretty dark in the middle, but in the end gets the desired effect:

```
let gradientColors: Array <AnyObject> = [topColor1.CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor]
let gradientLocations: Array <AnyObject> = [0.0, 1.0]
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations
gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);

let gradientColors2: Array <AnyObject> = [bottomColor1.CGColor, UIColor.clearColor().CGColor]
let gradientLayer2: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer2.colors = gradientColors2
gradientLayer2.locations = gradientLocations
gradientLayer2.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0);
gradientLayer2.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);


let gradientColors3: Array <AnyObject> = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, topColor2.CGColor]
let gradientLayer3: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer3.colors = gradientColors3
gradientLayer3.locations = gradientLocations
gradientLayer3.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
gradientLayer3.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);

let gradientColors4: Array <AnyObject> = [UIColor.clearColor().CGColor, bottomColor2.CGColor]
let gradientLayer4: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer4.colors = gradientColors4
gradientLayer4.locations = gradientLocations
gradientLayer4.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 1.0);
gradientLayer4.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
```

By Martin's suggestion, I create 4 gradients, each going from the desired corner's color to a `UIColor.clearColor()`, and I set the `startPoint`/`endPoint` accordingly to go from either bottom-left to top-right or top-left to bottom-right.

After this code, I simply add all of these gradient layers into my `blendView`, all with the same frame:

```
let background1 : CAGradientLayer = gradientLayer;
background1.frame = blendViewFrame;
let background2 : CAGradientLayer = gradientLayer2;
background2.frame = blendViewFrame;
let background3 : CAGradientLayer = gradientLayer3;
background3.frame = blendViewFrame;
let background4 : CAGradientLayer = gradientLayer4;
background4.frame = blendViewFrame;
blendView.layer.insertSublayer(background1, atIndex: 0)
blendView.layer.insertSublayer(background2, atIndex: 1)
blendView.layer.insertSublayer(background3, atIndex: 2)
blendView.layer.insertSublayer(background4, atIndex: 3)
```

So to finalize, it is possible to draw a 4 corner gradient with 4 different colors...the middle gets pretty dark, but above is how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11484823/1107580) solves this issue, also seems to get rid of the "dark effect". Its is not using a CAGradientLayer but rather a custom UIView.